# TeX capacity exceeded with TikZ-UML

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-uml

I have a problem using TikZ-UML, which is a nice library, but has some bug (or does not work in my configuration).
LaTeX goes into an infinite loop if I use all "do", "exit" and "entry" behaviors in a UML State Machine Diagram.

This example is simplified from the [documentation](http://perso.ensta-paristech.fr/~kielbasi/tikzuml/index.php?lang=en&id=doc#t-3).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-uml}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{umlstate}[name=state, do=b, exit=c, entry=d]{state}
  \end{umlstate}
\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

If I delete either the "do", the "exit" or the "entry", it is OK. With all of them, I got an error:

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
```

Do you have any hint?

Comment: Thanks for solving this problem. I fixed tikz-uml package and a new release will be available soon.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is indeed a bug. I don't know which version I have but if you open the `tikz-uml.sty` and go to line 2857, you find a recursion since the contents are not expanded (I think it was supposed to collect the text coming from those options);

```
\def\tikzumlStateText{\tikzumlStateTextOld \\ do/\umlstatedo}%
```

Change it to (since it is not on CTAN you probably have it in your local texmf),

```
\expandafter\def\expandafter\tikzumlStateText\expandafter{\tikzumlStateTextOld\\ do/\umlstatedo}%
```

Then it works, regardless of the order

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{umlstate}[name=state,
                entry=d,
                exit=b,
                do=c,
                ]{state}

  \end{umlstate}
\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

[image]